# Генератор паролей на python

Tags: python, циклы, случайные-числа

Не так давно стал изучать python и сейчас пытаюсь сделать первый пет-проект как генератор паролей. Основную функцию выполняет хорошо, но развить его дальше не могу. Мне нужно, чтобы изначально был выбор: сделать пароль автоматически, либо самостоятельно указывать необходимые регистры(цифры, буквы заглавные/прописные, спец. символы). Изначально делал на обычных if, сейчас пробую реализовать через for, но что-то делаю неверно и в итоге приходится постоянно лично указывать используемые символы.

```
from random import choice

digits = '0123456789'
uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
punctuation = '!#$%&*+-=?@^_' 
ally = digits + uppercase + lowercase + punctuation

chars = ''

pwd_pass = ['pwd_auto', 'pwd_digits', 'pwd_uppercase', 'pwd_lowercase', 'pwd_punctuation']
pwd_length = int(input('Введите желаемую длину пароля: '))
pwd_auto = input('Сгенерировать пароль автоматически? (y, n): ')
pwd_digits = input('Включить цифры (y, n): ')
pwd_uppercase = input('Включить uppercase (y, n): ')
pwd_lowercase = input('Включить цифры (y, n): ')
pwd_punctuation = input('Включить спец. символы (y, n): ')

for i in pwd_pass:
if pwd_auto == 'y':
    chars += ally
    break
else:
if pwd_digits == 'y':
chars += digits
if pwd_uppercase == 'y':
chars += uppercase
if pwd_lowercase == 'y':
chars += lowercase
if pwd_punctuation == 'y':
chars += punctuation

password = ''

for i in range(pwd_length):
password += choice(chars)

print('\n', password, '\n', sep='')
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вcего лишь переставил строчки в вашем коде:

```
from random import choice

digits = '0123456789'
uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
punctuation = '!#$%&*+-=?@^_' 
ally = digits + uppercase + lowercase + punctuation

chars = ''

pwd_length = int(input('Введите желаемую длину пароля: '))
pwd_auto = input('Сгенерировать пароль автоматически? (y, n): ')

if pwd_auto == 'y':
    chars += ally
else:
    pwd_digits = input('Включить цифры (y, n): ')
    pwd_uppercase = input('Включить uppercase (y, n): ')
    pwd_lowercase = input('Включить lowercase (y, n): ')
    pwd_punctuation = input('Включить спец. символы (y, n): ')
    if pwd_digits == 'y':
        chars += digits
    if pwd_uppercase == 'y':
        chars += uppercase
    if pwd_lowercase == 'y':
        chars += lowercase
    if pwd_punctuation == 'y':
        chars += punctuation

password = ''

for i in range(pwd_length):
    password += choice(chars)

print('\n', password, '\n', sep='')
```

Потому что зачем спрашивать сразу всё вначале, если в случае автоматической генерации кучу вопросов и задавать даже не надо.

---

Через цикл можно организовать вопросы.

```
from random import choices

digits = '0123456789'
uppercase = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
lowercase = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 
punctuation = '!#$%&*+-=?@^_' 

chars = ''

pwd_length = int(input('Введите желаемую длину пароля: '))
pwd_auto = (input('Сгенерировать пароль автоматически? (y, n): ') == 'y')

for text, seq in (('Включить цифры',         digits     ),
                  ('Включить uppercase',     uppercase  ),
                  ('Включить lowercase',     lowercase  ),
                  ('Включить спец. символы', punctuation)):
    if pwd_auto or (input(text + ' (y, n): ') == 'y'):
        chars += seq

password = ''.join(choices(chars, k=pwd_length))

print('\n', password, '\n', sep='')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас все работает как нужно. За второй вариант, через for, тоже спасибо, изучу более детально